# Can't install extensions for JupyterLab because Node.js and npm can't be found

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I installed Jupyter Lab via pip on a windows machine.

I installed Node.js via their website and used the wizard they provided.

I verified Node.js and npm are install on my machine:

[image]

Installed via pip, I can verify that flake8 extension is on my machine in the site-packages directory:

[image]

However, my "installed" section in Jup-Lab shows nothing - as does labextension list:

[image]

If I try to install extensions for Jup-Lab using the extension manager it tells me I have to install nodejs and npm

[image]

I've been searching for hours, but completely lost on how to resolve this.  Please help!

Comment: How did you install JupyterLab? Could it be that it is installed in a different environment and it makes the node.js invisible for it? You show that `node -v` from Windows terminal, but what happens if you run it in `Sandbox` venv?

Comment: Likewise with `jupyterlab-flake8` - where is it installed into?

Comment: Using conda rather than pip would make this much easier